# Define constructor prototype with object literal

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, constructor, object-literal

Which method below is best to define a constructor prototype and why?

Method 1:

```
MyConstructor.prototype.myFunction1 = function(){};
MyConstructor.prototype.myFunction2 = function(){};
```

Method 2:

```
MyConstructor.prototype = {
    myFunction1: function(){},
    myFunction2: function(){}
};
```

I'm mostly concerned about speed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would say there wouldn't be much of a difference. Using an object literal to assign to the Object.prototype is something you can't do if you're assigning the prototype *within* the constructor (which can be usefull sometimes).

Maybe you should write a little performance test using [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/).

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know this existed. I've even been looking for a tool like this.. albeit not very hard. Thanks I'll give it a test and report back my findings.

Answer (score 0):

```
var example = new MyConstructor();
```

under method 1:

```
example.constructor === MyConstructor;
```

under method 2:

```
typeof(example.constructor) === 'undefined';
```

The prototype object that comes with a function has a property `constructor` that points back to the function. If you assign to the proprties of that object, you keep the `constructor` property. If you overwrite the `prototype` property with a new object, you lose the `constructor` property.

The performance difference is minimal. Because `constructor` is so fragile, you can't really trust it, so I don't bother to preserve it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **method 1**. Using the **method 2**, everytime you create a *new* instance, you will "re-create" the methods, since they are inside the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Speaking further about the readability of your code,

method 1 is better than method 2.

Method 2 spend one more indentation. So it cause difficulty for reading codes.

Additionally, in my case,
I can't inference that whether this function is prototype method or just static member function when we see a function name part in the lower part of codes.

Personally, in conclusion,
I prefer method 2 if there not be much of a difference about performance.

Thanks!