# Defining methods on a prototype

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype

What's the difference between defining methods on a prototype individually vs via an object?

Example:

```
function Example() {
  this.Test();
}

Example.prototype.Test = function() {
  alert("Example");
};
```

instead of:

```
function Example() {
  this.Test();
}

Example.prototype = {
  Test: function() {
    alert("Example");
  }
};
```

Comment: In the first you're adding a method to the prototype. In the second one you're _replacing_ the prototype.

Comment: A similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848221/define-constructor-prototype-with-object-literal?rq=1

Comment: Does it affect how the prototype works though?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the difference between *adding to* the prototype and *replacing* it.

The only place it's really likely to make a difference is in this sort of scenario, which is relatively rare (and yet, I avoid replacing prototypes because of it):

```
var f = new Foo();

function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype = {
    test: function() { }
};

f.test(); // Fails!
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/EhUnIki/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/EhUnIki/1/edit)

That fails because the `f` object is created with `Foo`'s *original* prototype object, but then *later* you replace that prototype object with a new one. `f` still uses the old one, which doesn't have the `test` property on it.

This works:

```
var f = new Foo();

function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype.test = test: function() { };

f.test(); // Works
```

...because you're just adding to the object that `f` already uses as its prototype. [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/EhUnIki/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/EhUnIki/2/edit)

Provided `f` isn't created until *after* you've replaced `Foo.prototype` with a new object, it really doesn't make any significant difference.